# If spring security enabled . The rest api is not working

Tags: spring, spring-security

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@ComponentScan( basePackageClasses = {Implementation.class,ApiController.class})
public class ServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

spring security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApiController extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/b/**")
                .addFilterAfter(new TokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

TokenFilter to authenticate

```
public class TokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        if( ! isTokenValid(request))
        {
            response.setStatus(401);
        }
    }

    private boolean isTokenValid(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

api

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/b")
public class Implementation
{


    @GetMapping(path = "/freeze")
    @ResponseBody
    public String freezeAMovieSlot( )
    {
        return "HI";
    }
```

if I disable spring security I am getting the HI response
but for the above code the HI is not receiving in the response ..
and the response code is 200
What I am missing !!!!

Comment: What response do you get? Are there any exceptions? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SimonMartinelli NO ... Response is empty and 200

Comment: @M.Deinum please explain .. I just add a dummy token filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding

```
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

in the doFilterInternal method in TokenFilter class it worked .

it may be due to the filters got dropped in middle as I didnt chained it